# Show up dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i'm trying to follow the tutorial "Machine Learning" from Microsoft and there's a practical part. I just copied the code and tried to execute it straight from the terminal on Linux. When i run it, nothing is returned. From what I've seen in the video it should return a table with the values.

Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work?

Here is the code:

```
def sim_log_data(x1,y1,n1,sd1,x2,y2,n2,sd2):
    import numpy.random as nr
    import pandas as pd

# normal method draws normal samples from a Gaussian distribuition
    wx1 = nr.normal(loc = x1, scale=sd1, size=n1)
    wy1 = nr.normal(loc = y1, scale=sd1, size=n1)

# z1 and z2 are our labels, they have two possibilities, 0 or 1
    z1 = [1]*n1

    wx2 = nr.normal(loc = x2, scale=sd2, size=n2)
    wy2 = nr.normal(loc = y2, scale=sd2, size=n2)
    z2 = [0]*n2

# storing everything in DataFrames
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':wx1,'y':wy1, 'z':z1})
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x':wx2,'y':wy2, 'z':z2})

# concaternating the columns to be displayed
    return pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index = True)
sim_data = sim_log_data(1,1,50,1,-1,-1,50,1)
sim_data.head()
```

Thanks!

Comment: How are you running this script: at command line, an IDE like Spyder or Jupyter?

Comment: i'm running on the terminal with commands lines, but anyway the tip Tyler K gave worked :)

Comment: Then yes you do need to print to view such content on console. Please accept @TylerK's answer if it helped to resolve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df.head() returns a dataframe. Try printing it off to see it.

```
print(sim_data.head())
```